# CruiseControl.NET: Building a project in Debug and Release configurations

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I am using CruiseControl.NET to build a C# project. I am using an msbuild task to achieve this. I want to build the project in both Debug and Release mode irrespective of whether either mode fails. But If I put these as two msbuild tasks in the 'tasks' section of the project and if the first task fails, the second is not executed.

I could define them as two projects, but I want the Label to be synchronized across both the projects. Is there a way to do this?

One solution I have is make the 'Release' config project to trigger a build whenever the 'Debug' config project is built. But in that case, If someone force builds the 'Debug' config project then, the labels will get out of sync.

Comment: IF the debug build fails, why do you want to try and build the release ? makes no sense, even if will magically compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I think you will have to use a custom task to call MSBUILD from a CMD file and pass the debug/release mode into MSBUILD via cmd line args.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple  tasks for the project.

Note: See CC.NET preprocessor if you want to reduce tags duplication.